# How to hide a component in all nested routes with React router dom V6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'd like to hide a component depending on the route with react-router-dom v6. I could make it with exact path, but I'd also like to hide it in nested routes. I tried like this:

```
{location !== "/dashboard/*" && <Header />}
```

But it works only on the page `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/*`, which is not what I want. How could I fix this?

This is the full code:

```
const location = useLocation().pathname
const conditionLocation = location === "/dashboard" || location === "/dashboard/*"

return !conditionLocation && <Header />
```

Routes:

```
// Packages
import React from "react"
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"

// User
import Dashboard from "../pages/admin/Dashboard"
import EditAccount from "../pages/admin/EditAccount"

function Switch() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/edit" element={<EditAccount />} />
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default Switch
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Fix this issue using javascript regex:-

```js
{!(location.match(/^\/dashboard.*$/gim)) && <Header />}
```

Hope that works..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are wanting to render a `Header` component ***only*** on specific routes. You've not shared much context, but I understand you ***don't*** want to render the `Header` on any `"/dashboard"` path. You can achieve this with layout and `Outlet` components.

```
const HeaderLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Outlet /> // <-- wrapped Route components render into outlet
  </>
);
```

For the routes you want to render with the `Header` component render them into a route rendering the `HeaderLayout`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<HeaderLayout />}>
    ..... routes render into outlet with header
  </Route>
  <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="/dashboard/edit" element={<EditAccount />} />
</Routes>
```